# Library for effcient logfile compression

Tags: logging, compression, logfile

Some time ago I've found a compression library created specially for logfiles compression. I just remember that it can compress logfiles very efficiently. I've forgotten the name of the library (kind of database). I also remember that it creates read-only files and it was available under linux. Do you know the name of the library? Thanks in advance!